# How can i print columns in same rows with different 'codes' using csv python

Tags: python, csv, row, cell

Here is my code.csv file:

```
one,two,three
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

and code2.csv file:

```
,two,three
,2,3
,3,4
,4,5
```

this is my code.py file:

```
import csv

with open('code.csv', 'rb') as input, open('result.csv', 'wb') as output:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input)
        rows = [row for row in reader]
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

        writer.writerow(["new_one", "new_two", "new_three"])

        for row in rows:
                if 'two' in row:
                        writer.writerow(['',row["two"]])

        for row in rows:
                if 'one' in row:
                        writer.writerow([row["one"]])
```

The problem is that output is printed in different rows:

```
new_one,new_two,new_three
,2
,3
,4
1
2
3
```

How can I make the

```
for row in rows:
                    if 'one' in row:
                            writer.writerow([row["one"]])
```

to be printed like this

```
new_one,new_two,new_three
1,2
2,3
3,4
```

Without having to type it like this

```
 for row in rows:
                if 'one' in row and 'two' in row:
                        writer.writerow([row["one"],row["two"]])
```

Now if i would have code2.csv instead of code.csv, the latter (`if 'one' in row and 'two' in row:`) would give me error "'one' not found". So I need to have something like maybe "`for row in rows[1]:`" or something. Obviously that doesn't work, but something similar?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? 
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row[:-1])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** write row by row, not column by column. I think this should do it:

```
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow([row.get("one", ""), row.get("two", "")])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. We have been struggling for this for 3 days